# How to open popup, onclick of link in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

```html
 <label class="label-set">
 <input type="checkbox" class="" name="sameadr" />
  I agree to all statements of
  <a href="#" style="color: #ee1d24"> Terms of Use </a>
  </label>
```

How to open popup, onclick of link. simple popup should open as soon as user click on link

Comment: window.location = url;

or

 window.open(url);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In html
> give a id to your `a` tag.

```html
    <label class="label-set" id="mainId">
     <input type="checkbox" class="" name="sameadr" />
      I agree to all statements of
      <a href="#" id="newId" style="color: #ee1d24"> Terms of Use </a>
    </label>
```

> In javascript

```js
    document.getElementById("newId").addEventListener("click", function(){
       confirm("confirm this") // or your popop code
    })
```

Try this for vue.js

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" v-on:click="openPopup" id="newId" style="color: #ee1d24"> Terms of Use </a>
```

And write this inside your method

```js
    new Vue({
      el: '#mainId',
      methods: {
        openPopup: function () {
          alert('ok')
        }
      }
    })
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for info, in vuejs how to do the same

Comment: I have not tested. but write a small code for you. check it: `[previous code edited]`

Answer (score 1):

Make a modal component. Add a click to your a tag. When clicked show your modal component. After another action (confirm etc.) close and continue.

How to make a reusable modal component in Vue.js: [How to make a Modal Component](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-modal-component)

Comment: The link given here is perfect - very detailed instructions, And it works!